# gdalwarp netcdf input file has no raster bands

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, netcdf

I use netCDF data from ftp://podaac-ftp.jpl.nasa.gov/allData/merged_alt/L4/cdr_grid

I call `gdalwarp` as

> gdalwarp -of netCDF -ts 480 1080 ssh_grids_v1609_2014122612.nc o.nc

and get

`Input file ssh_grids_v1609_2014122612.nc has no raster bands.`

How can I change the resolution with gdalwarp of a netCDF file from the link above?

Below is `gdalinfo` output

```
gdalinfo -sd 4 ssh_grids_v1609_2014122612.nc
```

```
Warning 1: dimension #2 (Latitude) is not a Longitude/X dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #1 (Longitude) is not a Latitude/Y dimension.
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: ssh_grids_v1609_2014122612.nc
Size is 960, 2160
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-79.999997454216626,359.999989825117550)
Pixel Size = (0.166666661362951,-0.166666661953832)
Metadata:
  Latitude#axis=Y
  Latitude#bounds=Lat_bounds
  Latitude#long_name=latitude
  Latitude#point_spacing=even
  Latitude#standard_name=latitude
  Latitude#units=degrees_north
  Longitude#axis=X
  Longitude#bounds=Lon_bounds
  Longitude#long_name=longitude
  Longitude#point_spacing=even
  Longitude#standard_name=longitude
  Longitude#units=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.6
  NC_GLOBAL#date_created=2016-09-11T18:07:15.140757
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_max=79.916664
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_min=-79.916664
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_max=359.91666
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_min=0.083333336
  NC_GLOBAL#Institution=Jet Propulsion Laboratory
  NC_GLOBAL#ncei_template_version=NCEI_NetCDF_Grid_Template_v2.0
  NC_GLOBAL#summary=Sea level anomaly grids from altimeter data using Kriging technique, which gives best linear prediction based upon prior knowledge of covariance.
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_end=2014-12-26
  NC_GLOBAL#time_coverage_start=2014-12-26
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Sea Level Anormaly Estimate based on Altimeter Data
  NC_GLOBAL#version_number=1609
  NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={Time}
  NETCDF_DIM_Time_DEF={1,5}
  NETCDF_DIM_Time_VALUES=10951.5
  SLA_ERR#_FillValue=9.96921e+036
  SLA_ERR#add_offset=0
  SLA_ERR#coordinates=Sea Level Anomaly Error Estimate
  SLA_ERR#long_name=Sea Level Anomaly Error Estimate
  SLA_ERR#scale_factor=1
  SLA_ERR#standard_name=Sea Level Anomaly Error Estimate
  SLA_ERR#units=m
  Time#axis=T
  Time#bounds=Time_bounds
  Time#calendar=gregorian
  Time#long_name=Time
  Time#standard_name=time
  Time#units=Days since 1985-01-01 00:00:00
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (     -80.000,     360.000)
Lower Left  ( -79.9999975,   0.0000000)
Upper Right (      80.000,     360.000)
Lower Right (  79.9999975,   0.0000000)
Center      (       0.000,     180.000)
Band 1 Block=960x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=9.969209968386869e+036
  Metadata:
    _FillValue=9.96921e+036
    add_offset=0
    coordinates=Sea Level Anomaly Error Estimate
    long_name=Sea Level Anomaly Error Estimate
    NETCDF_DIM_Time=10951.5
    NETCDF_VARNAME=SLA_ERR
    scale_factor=1
    standard_name=Sea Level Anomaly Error Estimate
    units=m
```

Comment: I guess you need to specify the sub dataset explicitly, because some of those will be 1d dimension axes. Use gdalinfo on the file with no options to see those sds names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message makes sense since the netcdf file stores tables of different size and dimensions. If you run

```
gdalinfo ssh_grids_v1609_2014122612.nc >out2.txt
```

you see that there are 5 subdatasets stored inside the file. Alternatively, you can use [NASA GISS panoply](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/) to investigate the file, and maybe export its tables to CSV.

To resize a subdataset, you have to run either:

```
gdalwarp -of netCDF -ts 480 1080 NETCDF:"ssh_grids_v1609_2014122612.nc":SLA o1.nc
gdal_translate -of netCDF -outsize 480 1080 NETCDF:"ssh_grids_v1609_2014122612.nc":SLA o2.nc
```

for every dataset you are interested in.

Unfortunately, the X and Y coordinates in the 2D-tables are swapped.

You can translate them to tif files with this command line:

```
gdal_translate -of GTIFF NETCDF:"ssh_grids_v1609_2014122612.nc":SLA ssh.tif
```

the file looks like this:

[image]

To turn the image to the usual view, you might follow [How can I make QGIS interpret coordinates as long-lat instead of lat-long](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185616/how-can-i-make-qgis-interpret-coordinates-as-long-lat-instead-of-lat-long)

So the full workflow is:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT NETCDF:"ssh_grids_v1609_2014122612.nc":SLA ssh1.vrt
gdal_translate -of VRT -gcp 0 0 360 -80 -gcp 960 0 360 80 -gcp 0 2160 0 -80 -gcp 960 2160 0 80 ssh1.vrt ssh2.vrt
gdalwarp -r bilinear -t_srs EPSG:4326 ssh2.vrt ssh2.tif
gdal_translate -of VRT -a_ullr 0 80 360 -80 ssh2.tif ssh3.vrt
gdalwarp -t_srs WGS84 ssh3.vrt ssh.tif -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 --config CENTER_LONG 0
```

to get the right picture:

[image]

Comment: We can do far better than export to CSV with the gdal utilities. I consider that bad advice, though Panoply indeed is good for exploring and understanding the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great answer. However, I have a number of questions: (i) one of  -gcp is 360 while the actual coordinate is 359.91666 (similarly for others). Since I need not only image visualization but its further processing, what are the side effects? Or I should use precise coordinates?

Comment: (ii) I have errors `Warning 1: dimension #2 (Latitude) is not a Longitude/X dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #1 (Longitude) is not a Latitude/Y dimension.` produced both by `gdal_translate` and `gdalwarp`. Why is it so? How to force them to correctly recognise the axes?

Comment: (iii) is it mandatory to swap the axes using `gcp` before applying `gdalwarp`?

Comment: (iv) how can I convert the resulting GTiff back to netCDF preserving correct metadata as were given in the source file?

Comment: btw, I use WCT https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/wct/ which visualizes netCDF files with swapped coordinates correctly

Comment: Don't get confused about the extent and max/min values of the first and last pixel (mid-cell)! Corner coordinates are nearly full degrees, mid cell 0.08333 deg off. I get the same warnings, because GDAL does not like swapped Latitude and Longitude. It is just a metadata issue. The swapping is mandatory, if you want to use the file in any GDAL-based software together with other datasets. Finally, you can translate to netcdf. If parts of the metadata are mssing, you can add them with `-mo` options.

Comment: @AndreJ Thank you, when we provide GCP, we specify `top-left corner of a pixel` as I found here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122670/is-there-a-standard-for-the-coordinates-of-pixels-in-georeferenced-rasters  Though I still have concern about the warnings.